# SonarQube bug related to "Safe File handling"

Tags: java, sonarqube

The following error is being thrown when sonarQube analysis is done on my java project : `"Make sure this file handling is safe here".`

The lines of code for which this error is being thrown are :

```
final String filePath = "<<dummy_file_path>>";

File file = new File(filePath);
```

I declared the variable name containing `filePath` as `final` so that it cannot be modified. Also, I read the filePath variable value from a property file and avoided hard coding it. But still the same error is being thrown.

I am expecting a fix for the above specified piece of code such that after sonarQube analysis, an error wont be thrown for safe file handling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This actually is not a bug and doesn't relates to being `final` or not. 
It's a security rule from `owasp` (Open Web Application Security Project) and says that you should not access your file system directly with path as `String` coming from outside of application.

Now you can ask yourself if you need security rules in your app. E.g. one time run application - then I would disable OWASP rules for your project. 
Another alternative will be just disable this rule within source code.

Read more about this rule here:
https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/owasp/RSPEC-4797

Comment: Thanks but these rules are set by the client, so I cannot disable them. And they are asking for a solution and I am unable to give a fix for this issue.

Comment: Then your client wants application which follows OWASP rules. Try to read and understand why you have those warnings and use safe approach to comply with requirements.